# regex_match doesn't yield any results

Tags: c++, regex

I have this code snippet that I derived from something that I found online:

```
std::regex pieces_regex("([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)", std::regex_constants::basic);
std::smatch pieces_match;
std::string fname = "foo.txt";
cout << " fname " << fname << endl;
if (std::regex_match(fname, pieces_match, pieces_regex)) {
    std::cout << fname << '\n';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < pieces_match.size(); ++i) {
        std::ssub_match sub_match = pieces_match[i];
        std::string piece = sub_match.str();
        std::cout << "  submatch " << i << ": " << piece << '\n';
    }   
}
```

the pieces_regex constructor didn't work with my compiler, so I had to change the line from

```
std::regex pieces_regex("([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)");
```

to

```
std::regex pieces_regex("([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)", std::regex_constants::basic);
```

My regex_match line doesn't return anything now, and the size of pieces_match is zero. I tried adding several different flags to regex_match, like basic or match_any, but it didn't help.
The original code can be found here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match

Anyone have an idea what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try [`"\\([a-z]*\\)\\.\\([a-z]*\\)"`](https://ideone.com/xHcF12).

Comment: Does your compiler support `std::regex_constants::ECMAScript`? If yes, just use Aconcagua's solution. What is the compiler, BTW?

Comment: Both your code and Aconcagua's give me runtime erros. Trying your code gave me error code 5, still looking it up. I compile using
g++ main.cpp -std=c++11 -o main.o
and have compiler 4.7.2

Comment: Upgrade your compiler and enjoy ECMAScript compatible regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Standard regex (no second 'flags' argument) uses ECMA script as default. Try this instead:

```
std::regex pieces_regex("([a-z]+)\\.([a-z]+)", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);
//                                                                   ^
```

And you should see some results...

**EDIT:** As you have trouble with ECMA script: You chose the grammar unluckily: `extended`, `awk` and `egrep` all would swallow your expression as expected...

Comment: The ECMAScript is the reason I had to add the regex_constants::basic flag. With the ECMAScript, I get a runtime error

Comment: Everything but basic gives me runtime errors

Comment: @n00bprogrammer See comments to question (duplicate!), your compiler is outdated...